# How to get id from svgjs object

Tags: jquery, attr, svg.js

I tried using jquery's attr function to extract the id from an object generated as such:

```
var draw = SVG (parent).size (100,100)
```

but

```
draw.attr ('id')
```

doesn't work.  How do I get the id from draw?

Comment: SVG() produces a svg-object. To use jQuery convert it to a jQuery object. `$(draw.node).attr(...)`

Comment: Cha ching!  That did it.  Thanks Nils.  If you want to add this as an answer, I'll gladly click accepted.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The draw object is an SVG object. In order to use jQuery function it needs to be converted.

```
var draw = SVG (parent).size (100,100)
```

To convert it the first thing we need is the actual DOM-node, not the SVG object. `draw.node` is the reference to the actual SVG DOM-node. Once we have the DOM-node we convert that into a jQuery object `$(draw.node)`.

Now when we have the jQuery object we can for instance use the jQuery `attr` function

```
$(draw.node).attr(.id...)
```

---

However, it is possible to do this with SVG.js as well, and these are two ways to do it. I have included a fiddle as proof of concept.

```
draw.id()
```

or

```
draw.attr('id')
```

Here is a fiddle which show the one of these whays, http://jsfiddle.net/8AJ64/